# What is the purpose of mantra Diksha?

Tags: mantras, mantra-diksha

What will happen if we get mantra Diksha from any renowned organisation and chant it repeatedly with devotion and heart. Will I be able to experience Saguna Brahman , Kali, shiva , Ganesha Kartikeya etc.

What is the science behind the mantras. How can sound and vibration lead to getting any mystical experience ? Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Dīkṣā (दीक्षा)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17679/what-is-d%c4%abk%e1%b9%a3%c4%81-%e0%a4%a6%e0%a5%80%e0%a4%95%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%b7%e0%a4%be)

Comment: There are many posts on this topic .. you can go through them .. I am giving links of few such posts -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20367/4732, https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24317/4732, https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/31559/4732,